# When evaluating buildinputs on stdenv.mkderivation, which input is called first

Tags: nix, nixos

When calling `buildinputs` in trying to make a derivation, does it call each package individually and installing them or all of them at once?

Essentially, would `nix`, `git`, `bash`, and `python` be all called at the same time, or would they be called in order?

```
stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "Env";
  buildInputs = [ nix git bash python ]; 
...
```

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you mean by 'calling a package'. I'm guessing you think bulidInputs is doing something it isn't actually though. It's just a list of packages that can be referenced. 

The following section might be useful: https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-using-stdenv